# What does the mime type "gagt/sdf" mean in android when creating an Intent

Tags: android, mime-types, mime

```
Intent fileintent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
    fileintent.setType("gagt/sdf");
    try {
        startActivityForResult(fileintent, PICKFILE_RESULT_CODE);
    } catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) {
        Log.e("tag", "No activity can handle picking a file. Showing alternatives.");
    }
```

The above segment of code seems to magically start a file picker.

I have searched through the android developer doc but no explanation is found.

why does it work?

Comment: I'm somewhat suspicious that the MIME type there looks very much like someone just mashed the keys under their left hand for a while. Does this worth with *any* random unregistered MIME type?

Comment: @MattGibson same feelings, though googleing this "mime" will show mny results talking about how to show file selector, so i think it's a custom mime for some app that acts as a File Manager

Comment: @Yazan There's not actually that many unique results, if you check though them. It's mostly just those spammy/scammy sites that wrap other sites, like Stack Overflow, in a bunch of advertising to make some sly money. Those couple of pages of Google results are actually just the same couple of original references over and over again...

Comment: Also: If I ever write a popular Android app, I'm going to register to handle the "gagt/sdf" MIME type, just to annoy people who are using this exact trick :D

Comment: @MattGibson hahahahah that's a little bit Evil :)

Comment: The file picker open by this piece of code is the same of the file picker of Gmail application, so i suspect it is something from Google

Comment: Even if you type : fileIntent.setType("figfgsfdffddfle/*"); it still works and opens the file picker. So I don't think "gagt" means anything special.